# Adding an appearance with pdfbase

Tags: forms, dictionaries

[`pdfbase.sty`](https://github.com/agrahn/media9/blob/master/pdfbase.sty) (in the media9 package) appears to offer access to low-level pdf features, and [this chat.stackexchange.com post](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=50298556#50298556) (reproduced below) demonstrates its use for creating an appearance.

> Use \pdfxform to create an Appearance from savebox content. Example using pdfbase commands and Fontawesome:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{pdfbase}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\pbsPdfXform\pbs_pdfxform:nnnnn
\let\pbsPdfLastXform\pbs_pdflastxform:
\let\pbsPdfAnnot\pbs_pdfannot:nnnn
\def\pbsAppendToFields{\pbs_appendtofields:n{\pbs_pdflastann:}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\sbox{0}{\faIcon[regular]{square}}\pbsPdfXform{0}{1}{}{}{0}\edef\OffAppearance{\pbsPdfLastXform}%
\sbox{0}{\faIcon[regular]{check-square}}\pbsPdfXform{0}{1}{}{}{0}\edef\OnAppearance{\pbsPdfLastXform}%
\makebox[1.6ex][l]{\rule{0pt}{1.6ex}\leavevmode\pbsPdfAnnot{1.6ex}{1.6ex}{0pt}{%
```

1. The example tex appears to be truncated. How would I make use of this to actually show one of the new appearances? I've tried experimenting, but I'm out of my depth.
2. Could this be used to create an appearance for hyperref checkboxes? (Several posts indicate that their appearance is omitted from the appearance dictionary, making them appear unchecked when viewed in a browser.)

Comment: In the chat, you get the complete code by clicking on [(see full text)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/41/50298557) at the bottom of the code box. But the future approach should indeed be using the `l3pdffield` facilities as @Ulrike suggests.

Answer (score 4):

I reimplemented checkboxes to use appearances with the code from `pdfmanagement-testphase`. At some time in the future it will replace the code in hyperref. Some tips how to use it with hyperref is in the documentation `l3pdffield-testphase`.
In the following example both the bear and the box are checkboxes:

[image] [image]

Be aware that this requires a very new tex system, and that both `testphase` in the package names mean that the code is in the testphase—it is not yet compatible with everything. And currently the code handles only checkboxes. I still need to do the other types.

```
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{l3pdffield-testphase}
\usepackage{bearwear}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdffield_store_appearance:nn {checkbox/bear/Yes}
 {
   \tikz\bear\bearwear;
 }
\pdffield_store_appearance:nn {checkbox/bear/Off}
 {
   \tikz\bear;
 }

\newlength\bearheight
\newlength\bearwidth
\settoheight\bearheight{\tikz\bear;}
\settowidth\bearwidth{\tikz\bear;}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdffield_checkbox:n {name=bear,appearance=checkbox/bear,width=0.5\bearwidth,height=0.5\bearheight}

\quad 

\pdffield_checkbox:n {name=default}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

With adobe reader you should disable the option that it adds borders around text fields:

[image]

Comment: This looks great. Sorry, but how do I find and install these two testphase packages?

Comment: You get them in MiKTeX, texlive 2020, and texlive 2021. As texlive2020 is about to get freezed it probably will not get future versions, so if you want to install a new texlive better get 2021 directly.

Comment: Thanks. I must be misunderstanding something. I think I have texlive 2020 installed, yet when I try to build from the file you provided above using `pdflatex`, I get _"LaTeX Error: File \`pdfmanagement-testphase.sty' not found."_ Running `pdflatex -v` shows `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) ...` To get this installation, I downloaded `install-tl-unx.tar.gz` from http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet

Comment: Run tlmgr to check for updates.